# How to determine whether variables in joint PDF are independent

Tags: self-study, density-function, independence

I'm trying to solve the 2nd problem on [this site](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_2_5_solved_prob.php)

Here's the joint PDF:

$$
f_{x}{_,{_y}}(x,y)=\begin{cases}6e^{-(2x+3y)} & x,y \geqslant 0\\ 0 & otherwise \\ \end{cases}
$$

I need to figure out whether *X* and *Y* are independent. Which is true if:

$$
f_{x}{_,}{_y}(x,y) = f_x(x)f_y(y)
$$

The solution is:
$$
f_x(x) = 2e^{-2x}u(x), f_y(y) = 3e^{-3y}u(y)
$$

which shows the 2 variables are independent.

But, I don't understand what the *u* function is, or where it came from. Does anyone know?

I understand some of what is going on:

- For example: $2e^{-2x} * 3e^{-3y} = 6e^{-(2x+3y)}$
- I understand  *why* we expect the product of the 2 marginal PDFS to equal the joint PDFs (if the variables are independent)
- I just don't understand where the magic *u* is coming from

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: got it! this isn't my homework (I'm studying for a test), it's just a problem I found online -- I hoped that would be clear considering I posted that I also knew the solution already (and thus was trying to understand it)

Comment: PDFs have unit measure by definition.

Comment: What is "unit measure"?

Comment: There is no need for any guesswork. 

Using an indicator function '$\mathbf1$', clearly,

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=6e^{-(2x+3y)}\mathbf1_{x,y\ge 0}=\underbrace{2e^{-2x}\mathbf1_{x>0}}_{f_X(x)}\cdot \underbrace{3e^{-3y}\mathbf1_{y>0}}_{f_Y(y)}$$

Comment: Corrected to $2e^{-2x} * 3e^{-3y} = 6e^{-(2x+3y)}$.